# webservice message with images in listview android

Tags: android, web-services, image

I have a doubt to be clarified.

I am developing a chat application. I have a smiley button , a Edit Text and a send button.

1. I send message along with smileys to web service. I need to return the same data i sent from web service into list view where i display the list of messages from web service.

What i achieved is:   I am able to send the data with smileys. But when i get back the data from web service i get my data and [obj] icon along with my message. why am i not able to display image that is returned from web service. How can i check if my data is sent along with image to service or not. How can i achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to send the image to the service then try to check the request by printing it in logcat. may be your request is not in proper format. for image we need to send the bytearray stream, are you doing that? 
also when you get the data from webservice are you decoding the image data back to bitmap?

Comment: Hi, First thanks for taking time to respond to my question. I am newbie can you please give me a sample code or example if you have. I am bit confused with bytearray stream concepts. Any sample working example will be a great favor for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will get the code for uploding image to server at this link
http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/